# Linux - Redirecting part of output to a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redirect, exec

We can use EXEC command to redirect all the STDOUT and STDERR to a .log file, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 1> record.log 2>&1
echo begin redirecting

# from the script above, 'begin redirecting' will be redirected to record.log
# then we want to disable the redirecting and restore the STDOUT&STDERR     

echo return to STDOUT and STDERR

# here 'return to STDOUT and STDERR' will be print out
```

Does any one knows how to disable the redirecting(both STDOUT and STDERR)?
In this way, we can just redirect part of the output to a file by using exec command.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Link file descriptor #6 with stdout/stderr
exec 6>&1 2>&1

exec 1> record.log 2>&1
echo begin redirecting

# restore and close file descriptor #6
exec 1>&6 2>&1 6>&-

# from the script above, 'begin redirecting' will be redirected to record.log
# then we want to disable the redirecting and restore the STDOUT&STDERR     

echo return to STDOUT and STDERR
```

Comment: At the risk of nitpicking, after the restoration, they are merged.  Shouldn't you save them separately, e.g. `exec 4>&1 5>&2` and then restore them separately, e.g. `exec 1>&4 4>&- 2>&5 5>&-`?

Comment: @John1024: In this script both stdout/stderr are handled together only. But what you are suggesting can also be done. I leave it up to the OP.

Comment: @user3514137: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not limit the scope of the redirection with a sub-shell? E.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

(
    exec 1> record.log 2>&1
    echo begin redirecting

)

echo This goes to stdout
```

You might have issues if you set variables in the inner scope though. Depends how your program is structured.